# Optimizing a MySQL DELETE Query which is blocking the database

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, sql-delete

I need a suggestion for optimizing following mysql delete query:

```
$group_id = '1234';

     // DELETE GROUP DISCUSSION POSTS 
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_groupposts 
                     WHERE grouppost_grouptopic_id 
                     IN (SELECT grouptopic_id from table_grouptopics 
                         WHERE grouptopic_group_id='{$group_id}')
                    ");

echo "DEL groupposts: " . mysql_affected_rows() . "<br />";
```

Having a large database and it takes up to 70 seconds to run the query, even there are no discussion posts.

Any ideas how to speed up the process?

Comment: Since you've flagged this with InnoDB - put a foreign key index on the relevant tables with the proper relationship and an `ON DELETE CASCADE` restriction; then just `DELETE FROM table_grouptopics WHERE table_grouptopics.grouptopic_group_id = ?` (with a prepared statement to replace the `?` placeholder) and allow the database to deal with the cascading delete.

Comment: @CD001 To be honest, I just shortly switched to innoDB and still new to this ("put a foreign key index").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use join for the delete operation instead of sub-query

```
delete tg from table_groupposts tg
join table_grouptopics gt on gt.grouptopic_id = tg.grouppost_grouptopic_id
where gt.grouptopic_group_id='$group_id'
```

Make sure that the joining keys are indexed and if not do as

```
alter table table_groupposts add index grouppost_grouptopic_id_idx(grouppost_grouptopic_id);

alter table table_grouptopics add index grouptopic_id_idx(grouptopic_id);
```

And finally

```
alter table table_grouptopics add index grouptopic_group_id_idx(grouptopic_group_id)
```

Comment: If I don't add an index before, would it still work with using the join? When I understood correctly, adding the index is only to extra speed up, right?

Comment: Yes the index will speedup. For smaller set of data you will not realize it, but when there is a large set of data using index on the join condition will speed up the operation. And adding index to the column in where condition will give extra boost to the query.